# Need to apply countifs in vba with given multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel table with sample entries below. There are many random report IDs, I have printed for report_id=155. I want to count all Get_Days entries where get_days are less than 7. Like in below example there are 6 such entries. Out of these 6, 2 are pending_with Lead(last 2 rows are 0), 4 are pending_with Owner(1,2,3,6).

Input Table in Sheet1:

```
 Report_ID  Get_Days  Pending_With
    155        15        Owner
    155        14        Owner
    155        13        Owner
    155        10        Owner
    155        9         Owner
    155        8         Owner
    155        7         Owner
    155        6         Owner
    155        3         Owner
    155        2         Owner
    155        1         Owner
    155        21        Owner
    155        20        Owner
    155        17        Owner
    155        16        Owner
    155        0         Lead
    155        0         Lead
```

Print Output table in Sheet2:

```
Report ID  Get_Days_LessThan7   PendingOwnerLT7  PendingLeadLT7  
155             6                    4               2
```

Comment: `Range("G2:G")` does not make sense. You must use (probably) `Range("G2:G" & lastRow)` if you have the last row number calculated.

Comment: Noted this, any help on the above logic pls. Thanks.

Comment: In order for us tu better understand what you need, maybe it will be good to post (at least, a picture but better something editable) your initial situation and then what you want to accomplish. The code result... Otherwise, I must confess, I did not understand very well what is your need... The way you tried is not clear enough. At least for me.

Comment: Okay, let me do a better editing.

Comment: Can you now explain the logic you want to apply? Counting of values of `Get_Days` column less then 7 is easy, but you try saying something about `Pending_With`, which is not so clear (adding "Pending...LT7"). What logic to be applied to naming the columns headers for such a situation?

Comment: I hope this is clearer, I cant paste screenshots as I am in restricted mode.

Comment: See, I want to apply multiple 2 conditions: 1) For report_id=155 count get_days less than 7.       2) Then, also count with whom it is pending with for which there are 2 columns. PendingOwner, PendingLead. How many counts less than 7 where Pending_With = Owner and get_days less than 7, which is 4. Similarly for Onwer it is 2, In total there are 6 entries less than 7. This represents breakup of count less than 7

Comment: I think I understood the necessary logic. Only the naming of the two resulted column (transforming of `Lead` in `Pending_LeadLT7`) is not clearly defined. But, I will prepare an answer using what I could deduce from what I could see...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CountIfs`-function for multiple conditions. Assuming your data in `A1:C100`, formulas could look like

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,155,B1:B100,"<=6")
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,155,B1:B100,"<=6",C1:C100,"Owner")
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,155,B1:B100,"<=6",C1:C100,"Lead")
```

Of course you can change the formula to get the criterias from other cells, so instead of having the ID hardcoded to 155, you can write it to a cell (let's say `D2`) and then change the `155` in the formula with `D2`, or write the number of days into `D3` and change the criteria to `"<="&D3`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,D2,B1:B100,"<="&D3)
```

**UPDATE** With VBA:

```
Function CountMe(ID As Long, Optional days As Long = 6, Optional user As String = "")

    Dim data As Range
    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C100")

    Dim idCol As Range, dayCol As Range, UserCol As Range
    Set idCol = data.Resize(, 1)
    Set dayCol = idCol.Offset(0, 1)
    Set UserCol = idCol.Offset(0, 2)

    If user = "" Then
        CountMe = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(idCol, ID, dayCol, "<=" & days)
    Else
        CountMe = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(idCol, ID, dayCol, "<=" & days, UserCol, user)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: There are 1000s of Report_IDs so i just posted for sample report_id=155. I dont want to hardcode it, it can change. For each report ID i want to count these, and I need to apply in VBA code. Report ID is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try please the next code. It doesn't use `Sumproducts`. It works only in memory using arrays and drops the result at once, at the end of the code. The below `Sub` accepts parameters and can be called for any ID:

```
Private Sub FindOutputTable(sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, ID As String)
   Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, lastR2 As Long
   Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long


   lastRow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   lastCol = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr1 = sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(2, 1), sh1.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).value
   If lastR2 = 1 Then 'if the sheet is blank, the array will also include the headers
        ReDim arr2(1 To 2, 1 To 4)
   Else   'the array will contain only one row, keeping the necessary values
        ReDim arr2(1 To 1, 1 To 4)
   End If
   arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 1) = ID' the row where ID will be returned is chosen according to the lastR value
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
        If arr1(i, 1) = ID Then
            If arr1(i, 2) < 7 Then
                arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 2) = arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 2) + 1
                If arr1(i, 3) = "Owner" Then
                    arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 3) = arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 3) + 1
                ElseIf arr1(i, 3) = "Lead" Then
                    arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 4) = arr2(IIf(lastR2 = 1, 2, 1), 4) + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
   Next
   If lastR2 = 1 Then 'For a blank sheet, the headers are also added
        sh2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr2, 1), UBound(arr2, 2)).value = arr2
        sh2.Range("A1").Resize(, 4).value = Split("Report ID,Get_Days_LessThan7,PendingOwnerLT7,PendingLeadLT7", ",")
   Else   'Only the collected values will be returned
        sh2.Range("A" & lastR2 + 1).Resize(UBound(arr2, 1), UBound(arr2, 2)).value = arr2
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, be careful and use your sheets (sheet1 and sheet2). For testing purpose I used active sheet and the last sheet for returning the result...

In order to test it, please use the next code:

```
Sub testFindOutputTable()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, ID As String

    ID = "155"
    Set sh1 = ActiveSheet                  'you may use here your sheet1
    Set sh2 = Worksheets(Worksheets.count) ' you will use here your sheet2
    FindOutputTable sh1, sh2, ID
End Sub
```

You can also iterate, in the above testing sub, between all your `IDs`. If you do not understand how, I can help you with an example. All Your `IDs` must be input in an array and iterating between the array elements you can accomplish running the sub for all your ID`. The code, firstly, fill the column headers and then only the collected values.

The variant involving iteration between existing `ID` should look like the next sub:

```
Sub testFindOutputTable()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, El As Variant, arrID As Variant

    arrID = Split("155,156", ",")
    'ID = "155"
    Set sh1 = ActiveSheet                  'you may use here your sheet1
    Set sh2 = Worksheets(Worksheets.count) ' you will use here your sheet2
    For Each El In arrID
        FindOutputTable sh1, sh2, CStr(El)
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use instead of "155,156" as many IDs you need, but separated by comma. If you have, somewhere in a range, ol those IDs, you can input them at once in an array, using something like this: `arrID = range("yourRange").value`

Comment: Have you hardcoded the report_id-155. I have 1000s of IDs want to generalize it.

Comment: Like I've written, changing `ID = "155"` with another one, it will work for that specific `ID`. I offered myself to transform it in something needing parameters. Would that be a useful idea for you? I will transform it, anyhow...

Comment: I am just trying to understand your code, can you pls help me understanding what are we doing from this line onwards: If lastR2 = 1 Then
        ReDim arr2(1 To 2, 1 To 4) in function FindOutputTable. Apologies I am very new to vb

Comment: @Nipen Mahajan: OK, I will explain that putting some comments on the code. But, did you test it? Did you understand how to call the function? If yes, did it work as you need?

Comment: @Nipen Mahajan: Did my comments make things more clearer? If not, do not hesitate to ask about specific code parts. But firstly, did you check it?